# Matlab lsqcurvefit fitting more than one parameter

Tags: matlab, parameters

I have some x- and ydatapoints (stored in x and y) and I would like to fit a function (called deg) to them.

```
deg=@(para,x)1-para(1)*log10(1+x/para(2));
para0=[0.1; 1e9];
[para,resnorm] = lsqcurvefit(deg,para0,x,y);
```

The code works so far but when I look at the fitting parameters in 'para' then I see that only the first one has changed (from 0.1 to 0.0675). The second parameter always stays at the value I type in para0 (in this case 1e9). 
How do I get matlab to change both parameters for fitting?

Kind regards
Manuel

Comment: I'd use a lower second starting parameter, because `x/1e9` is pretty small and will therefore not have much influence on the fitting.

Comment: With smaller values of the starting parameter, para(2) changes, but the result is highly dependent on what I type as start value in para0. How can I make the fitting margin narrower?

Comment: Narrow in which way? Did you have a look at MATLAB's multistart feature?

Comment: Narrow in the way that the fitting algorithm stops somewhere and gives me parameters. The 'somewhere' is probably defined by a confidence level which states that the fitting process stops when the level is reached which means that the fitting curve differs x from the data points.

I hope that was clear. I just began to fit data in matlab and have just experience so far with fitting in origin. I trust the fitting parameters I get from origin, but not from matlab because I get different ones for different sets of parameter start values. Should I use another fitting function than lsqcurvefit?

Comment: You could try using a custom equation of form `1-a*log10(1+x/b)` in MATLAB's `cftool` and play around with the various settings to see if you can get near the values from origin.